# What is the mnimum memory for Worklight Analytics?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I'm trying to find where it documents the minimum memory requirements for the Worklight analytics component.

I can see the disk space and the fact that it needs a 64-bit Linux or AIX platform but no mention of memory.  (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024838)

Have I just missed it somewhere?

The reason I ask is that I've just installed it on a Red Hat 6.2 vm and it complained that it needed to have 8GB minimum before I could install it.  Easy enough for me as I installed on a VM, but it wouldn't have been had I tried to install it on a physical server if I didn't know before hand.

I need to send the requirements to an operations team and I'd like to know where I can point them to the full hardware requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Operational Analytics Getting Started Module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/10_02_Operational_Analytics.pdf) on slide 9 or in [IBM Information Center here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_install_websphere_analytics_platform.html&resultof=%2522analytics%2522%2520%2522analyt%2522%2520%2522ram%2522%2520).

From the document:

```
* Supported operating systems:
– AIX V6.1 and V7.1 on ppc 64-bit
– Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 6 Server editions on x86-64
– Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 5 Update 6 Advanced Platform on x86-64
– SUSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES) 10 and 11 on x86-64

* 200 MB of disk space for installation
* 8 GB of RAM required
* Local file system with minimum 
* 100-GB disk space (ideally more)
* Python 2.6.x or Python 2.7.x
* Root access for installation
* Ability to open firewall ports
```

Comment: Thanks for that, are these documents classed as official documentation in the same way as the support notes?  Seems strange that this is not included on the support page I posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can find system requirements specification for [Operational Analytics here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_install_websphere_analytics_platform.html&resultof=%2522analytics%2522%2520%2522analyt%2522%2520%2522ram%2522%2520)